# Clicking "next" in the mods selection dialog is extremely slow

Tags: civilization-5

When I go to the "MODS" option in the main game menu, it shows me a list of all installed mods and offers me the chance to enable/disable them, to get more mods, and to continue to the next screen where I can start or load a game:

[image: MODS]

However, when I click "NEXT" to go to the next screen it takes a relatively long time - feels like a minute or two - to proceed to the next screen:

[image: NEXT]

It's quite annoying. Is there a way to solve this slowdown?

Comment: That's the game loading up the mod. On my old computer, in civ 4, it could take up to 15 minutes to load C2C, because it about tripled the amount of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, this "slowdown" is as noted by @SaintWacko caused by your game loading in your active mods.

In the list on the screenshot I'm expecting "ingame editor" and "R.E.D. modpack" to be the biggest mods and thus causing the most slowdown.

The only way to reduce the slowdown is to use less/smaller mods.

Answer (score 0):

the more mods you have, the longer it takes to retrieve the mod data.